# Python/Libtorrent: Retrieve metadata from a magnet link without downloading files

Tags: python, bittorrent, libtorrent, magnet-uri, libtorrent-rasterbar

I'm trying to just get the torrent name or a list of files in the torrent without actually downloading them.

This is my current code, it is functional but slow, as it downloads the torrent contents.

```
import libtorrent as lt
import time

ses = lt.session()
params = {
    'save_path': 'media/',
    'storage_mode': lt.storage_mode_t(2),
    'paused': False,
    'auto_managed': True,
    'duplicate_is_error': True
}
handle = lt.add_magnet_uri(ses, "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:9fea16aff4ece16e04f98321668a265f0fd22b7e&dn=archlinux-2017.08.01-x86_64.iso&tr=udp://tracker.archlinux.org:6969&tr=http://tracker.archlinux.org:6969/announce", params)
while(not handle.has_metadata()):
    time.sleep(1)

print(handle.get_torrent_info().name())
```

I've also tried using `lt.parse_magnet_uri()`, but this does not return what I am looking for, or much of anything really past the info hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving my problem by utilizing the `'file_priorities'` property in `params`. This still downloads the files until the metadata is retrieved, however, so I just saved them to a temporary directory.

```
import libtorrent as lt
import time
import tempfile

ses = lt.session()
params = {
    'save_path': tempfile.mkdtemp(),
    'storage_mode': lt.storage_mode_t(2),
    'auto_managed': True,
    'file_priorities': [0]*5
}

handle = lt.add_magnet_uri(ses, "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:9fea16aff4ece16e04f98321668a265f0fd22b7e&dn=archlinux-2017.08.01-x86_64.iso&tr=udp://tracker.archlinux.org:6969&tr=http://tracker.archlinux.org:6969/announce", params)
while(not handle.has_metadata()):
    time.sleep(1)

print(handle.get_torrent_info().name())
```